# Converting a String to Control type

Tags: c#, winforms

I can find out if component with some name exist on the current `Form` like following code.

```
if (!this.Controls.ContainsKey("MyControlName"))
{
      //do anything
}
```

but how I can Identify whether it is `TextBox` or not.

I tried this

```
string viewIdentifier = "MyControlName";
string val = null;

if (viewIdentifier is Textbox)
{
    val = viewidentifier.Text;
}
```

how I can convert `MyControlName` to `Control` type from `string`?

Comment: via the indexer: `this.Controls["MyControlName"]` there is also `this.Controls.Find()`

Comment: @Alex But how to identify whether it is textbox or not?

Comment: I have name stored in string variable not in Control

Comment: DownVoting is correct but please give a reason for that,,,so that new users can better understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
string val = (this.Controls[viewIdentifier] as TextBox)?.Text;
```

Here

1. We seach for `Control` within `Controls` by its name - `viewIdentifier`
2. `as TextBox`: try cast the control into `TextBox` (`null` if is not `TextBox`)
3. `?.Text` if cast succeeds, get `Text` (`null` otherwise)

**Edit** If you want `is` (let's amend your current code) you can implement the routine with *pattern matching* (C# 7.0):

```
  string viewIdentifier = "MyControlName";
  string val = null;

  // viewIdentifier is String, when this.Controls[viewIdentifier] is Control
  // ... is TextBox textbox: if left side matches TextBox pattern
  // then textbox is a matched pattern to work with 
  if (this.Controls[viewIdentifier] is TextBox textbox) {
    val = textbox.Text;
  }
```

Comment: Isn't there a possibility that it exists as a Textbox and Text is null?

Comment: @Cetin Basoz: *no*, `Text` can't be `null` but empty string

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ: Try assigning `null` to `Text` and see: `myTextBox.Text = null; if (myTextBox.Text == null {MessageBox.Show("It's null"); else if (myTextBox.Text == "") MessageBox.Show("It's an empty string")})`

Comment: Thanx JayMee and Dmitry I will try this

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - no, you are correct, I meant this is incorrect. This as in not yours that.

Answer (score 0):

```
string viewIdentifier= "MyControlName";

var hasTextBoxWithThisName = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(c => c.Name == viewIdentifier);
```

EDIT:

```
var t = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
            .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == viewIdentifier);
if (t != null)
{
     var text = t.Text;
}
```

Comment: You simply have access to it then. Editing to show you. Your question was about checking it exists or not.

Comment: thanx Cetin I will try this

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but, probably, you should put it as `this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == viewIdentifier);` - typo in `Default`; I don't see any reason for `Single` here; please, drop  misleading (unedited) solution

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, unedited version is not misleading. He was asking how to check if there is a control named "xxx" and if that is a textbox.